# Desktop computer for research purposes

Tags: desktop

The next year I will get a budget of circa 2000$ to buy a desktop computer to start my PhD program in control systems engineering.

In particular, I know that I will use such computer to:

1. solve general optimization problems not in real time, for example to train neural networks;
2. solve specific optimization problems in real time, for example to run [MPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_predictive_control) controllers;
3. run (in real time) some new types of [MHT](https://www.sto.nato.int/publications/STO%20Educational%20Notes/STO-EN-IST-134/EN-IST-134-02.pdf) filters, which are characterized by the nice property of having a lot of operations that can be computed independently and parallel in time;
4. run (not in real time) some computational demanding Monte Carlo simulations.

I will write the code mainly in MATLAB, Phyton, C++ and C.

I've ***never*** bought the single components to build a desktop computer on my own and I'm quite scared to waste my budget.

It will be useful for me to have some general information, for example what is the state of the art, about the type of hardware that I need and what I can afford.

It will be useful also just some good online references about the topic.

Comment: For the kind of workload you described, any money spent on the CPU is well spent. More cores will help with real-time processing if it is particularly complex, or if you use something like the MHT filter you described. If you are going to use GPU-accelerated machine learning then it is worth looking at a decent GPU to speed up training times. You could spend $2000 on the GPU alone for that though.

Comment: Also to clarify: This is $2000 USD? What country are you in? People will need to know this to recommend specific parts for you.

Comment: For the sake of clearness, I'm in Italy and I will get 5000€ to buy 3 computers. Hence I'm considering 2000$ USD as a budget for a single computer.